# Why is Dart's Datetime.parse not a factory constructor?

Tags: dart

Dart's Datetime class has a number of named constructors, but `DateTime.parse()` is not one of them. Instead, `DateTime.parse()` is a static method which returns a DateTime. To me, it makes sense as a constructor (since you are generating a new DateTime object in a manner not too different from the `Datetime.utc()` constructor).

Theories I've come up with are to mirror the fact that `int.parse` is not a constructor or to allow easier chaining (you don't need to use the cascade operator with a static method). But maybe there is another reason that I'm not thinking of. Does anyone know why they didn't make it a named constructor?

Comment: Interestingly enough, it used to be a factory constructor new DateTime.fromString() and was explicitly changed to the static parse that we have now: https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/commit/6d96912d9b618259d4e2310c2a302f85f807310f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More explanation for the same change for Uri.parse: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.dart.general/17081

> "parse" is special. The question is: do you see parsing as an
>   operation that does something and ends up giving you the result, or do
>   you see the string as data to construct a new element. If you see it
>   as the earlier, then "parse" should be a static function. If you see
>   the string as the data, then it should be a named constructor.

And then, of course, there is consistency.